# Custom templates callInWindow

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am using the new custom template feature but I am still fairly new to the general concept and I was looking for opinions on the following code, I want to call a global function that sits on my application from GTM, will this code work for my custom tag?

```
const log = require('logToConsole'); // Console api
const query = require('queryPermission'); // Query api
const callInWindow = require('callInWindow'); // Call function in window api

if (query('access_globals', 'execute', 'OBJ.tracking.add')) { // Trying to access the method
    log('data =', data); // USE ONLY IN DEBUG
    callInWindow( 'OBJ.tracking.add' , [data.tagLabel, data.tagDetail]); // Send event
    data.gtmOnSuccess();
}
else {
  data.gtmOnFailure();
}
```

Where `OBJ.tracking.add` has `execute` only permissions.
Thanks!

Comment: Looking at this a year later again I see that there is a typo in the code ('excute' instead of 'execute'), so this would not have run in any case.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks for reviewing this after so long, I fixed the typo so the question can be more useful to other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just been through this. Your syntax is correct, but that does not guarantee that this will actually run - that depends on what "OBJ" is actually doing. If it modifies the prototype chain at some point the code will not run (one of the reasons being that GTM custom templates actually run on a copy of the global object, not the object itself).

So while your code is fine, but it might not run due to limitations of the [sandboxed Javascript](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/sandboxed-javascript), and in that case there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification and the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Elke's answer is correct in that the copyFromWindow api does a deep copy of objects. The [callInWindow](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/api#callinwindow) api will call the actual object on window, passing it the rest of the arguments. In your case you probably want to call callInWindow passing the label as the second argument, and the detail as the third, unless Obj.tracking.add expects an array as an argument.